# MVC web app broken with a 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, dbconnection

I've been supporting an MVC app for some time. I had to update the Newtonsoft.Json and Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompiler and I'm now getting a 504 time out when on the live site. It works fine in localhost (hence deploying the updates). I've searched on here and it might be an IISExpress issue maybe. But any help/suggestions would be massively appreciated

Here's the stack trace:

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)]
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +353
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +118 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +268
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +315 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +128
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +265 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +133 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +964 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +503 System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +18 System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +234
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +321

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +741
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions) +167
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +60 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction) +261 System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +206
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction) +300
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +145
Happipod.Infrastructure.ExceptionLoggingFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) +1338
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception) +186 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +166 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38 System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38 System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +431
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +75
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +158

Could it be my IIS or the maybe something with the DBConnection? Hope that's not a red herring?!? Looking forward to hearing from you experts

Comment: Refer to this document to follow the steps to troubleshoot network-related or instance-specific errors when establishing a connection to SQL Server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-connection

Comment: The stack trace contains error messages (SqlException) related to the SQL Server connection. You need to ensure that the SQL Server instance is running and accessible. Check that the connection string in the application configuration is correct and points to the correct SQL Server instance.
Also check to see if there are any firewall or network issues blocking the connection between your web server and SQL Server.